# how to integrate android mobile clone at server machine

Tags: android, clone

I am trying to create a clone of android mobile device on server persistently and synchronized with device. my basic need is to have an architecture such that client application(android application in device) should communicate with its clone residing on server.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dalvik VM check out wikipedia link of that. It may help you.